# makefile CFLAGS ignore $(mysql_config --libs)?

Tags: mysql, c, makefile

I make a toy makefile example to test mysql, but the makefile does not recognize mysql_config.
this is the makefile script:

```
CFLAGS = -g -O2  -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic $(OPTFLAGS)
LDLIBS = $(OPTLIBS)
SOURCES =$(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS = asd
all: LDLIBS += $(mysql_config --libs_r) -lm
     CFLAGS += -Isrc $(mysql_config --cflags)
all: $(OBJECTS)
```

When i run make all, it only execute:

```
cc -g -O2  -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic  -Isrc     asd.c   -lm -o asd
```

Where did all the mysql CFLAGS and LDLIBS go? Or is there something wrong with my script?

this returns when i type 'mysql_config --cflags' in the shell, for demonstration:

```
-I/usr/include/mysql
```

Comment: Access to the symbol `$(mysql_config --libs_r)` will not yield the contents of your script. You maybe wanted to write `$(shell mysql_config --libs_r)`

Comment: Please don't, and don't recommend, using make's `$(shell ...)` function inside a recipe (which is what adding it to these variables will do).  It's can lead to difficult-to-understand problems (although not, most likely, in this situation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content `$(mysql_config --libs_r)` is intended to ask the *shell* to invoke that command and replace the string with its output.

But, *make* uses the `$(...)` syntax to expand variables.  So, your attempt at running a shell command `mysql_config --libs_r` is actually being interpreted as expanding a make variable named `mysql_config --libs_r`, of which there is not one, and so you get an empty string here.

You need to escape the `$(...)` syntax from make so that it's passed to the shell.

Also, your indentation seems to imply you want both LDLIBS and CFLAGS to be target-specific variables on the `all` target, however if that's really what you want you have to write the target multiple times; there can only be one target-specific variable assignment per line.

You want this:

```
all: LDLIBS += $$(mysql_config --libs_r) -lm
all: CFLAGS += -Isrc $$(mysql_config --cflags)
```

There are some efficiency issues with this as it will run `mysql_config` *twice* for *every* compile and link operation.  Much more efficient would be something like:

```
mysql_LIBS := $(shell mysql_config --libs_r)
mysql_FLAGS := $(shell mysql_config --cflags)
```

then use the make variables `$(mysql_LIBS)` and `$(mysql_FLAGS)`

Comment: Didn't you just say that you don't recommend the usage of 'shell' earlier? If I want to , can I change the declaration to something like this? Mysql_lib = $$(mysql_config --libs)

Comment: and somehow indentation still work in my computer without having to use a backlash.

Comment: The indentation "works" because you're setting a global variable, which in this case is probably equivalent to setting a target-specific variable.  E.g., it's exactly the same as setting that variable without any indentation at all.

Comment: I said, don't use `$(shell ...)` _in a recipe_.  By using `:=` you're going to expand that variable only one time, when it's defined in the makefile.  In that case you want to use `$(shell ...)` so that you run the commands one time.  If you use `Mysql_lib = $$(mysql_config --libs)` that's identical to what you were doing before, and will cause that command to be run again and again every time you access it.  For libs it's not so bad since you do it once for link, but for cflags you'll do it for every compile.

Comment: If you want to see it in action you can add an `$(info ...)` which will print something out every time the variable is expanded; everywhere `mysql_config` is run add in `$(info running mysql_config)`.  Make will show that string every time it expands the variable (without disturbing the run of make) and you can see how many times it happens.